# Is it okay to spawn a thread from django post save signal?

Tags: python, json, django, multithreading, django-models

I have post_save signal on one of my models which calls json.dumps on a large python dictionary. I want to call this json.dumps in a separate thread so it may not slow down the save call on my model. I was wondering if it is okay to spawn a new thread from inside a post_save signal? I have read that post_save signals are themselves thread so would it be okay to spawn another Python thread from it?

EDIT: I cannot use a celery task for some reason.

Answer (score 2):

It's not a direct answer to your question but I found this hint from one of the answers in [Is Django post_save signal asynchronous?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11899088/is-django-post-save-signal-asynchronous). My post_save signal handler creates a [Celery](http://celeryproject.org/) task.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know where you would have read that signals are executed in threads, because it is not at all true. Django does not do anything with threads, and neither should you: if you want to execute something out of process, use a task queue system like Celery.