# Celery Signals vs Django Signals

Tags: django, celery, django-celery

Are celery signals asynchronous unlike django signals that are synchronous? Just curious for instance `task_success` signal from celery vs `post_save` signal from django.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is Django post\_save signal asynchronous?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11899088/is-django-post-save-signal-asynchronous) - take a look at @Bouke answer

Answer (score 0):

Some celery signals are executed in-process (i.e., semi-synchronous), and others may be executed out-of-process and asynchronously.  You can read the documentation [here](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/signals.html) to determine which is which.